# Visualizing friction?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to simulate a mecanum wheel using a plugin which dynamically sets directional friction ([related question](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8737/mecanum-simulation-possible-using-directional/)). One of the tricky parts is that it's difficult to assess whether my plugin is having the desired results without a way to visualize the friction— I can show the contact points between the wheels and the ground plane, but fdir1/mu/mu2 are completely opaque.

Is there some way to visualize these which I'm not seeing, or a plugin which can add an overlay to gzclient?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9030/visualizing-friction?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As far as I know, there isn't a way to visualize friction forces in the 3D scene, but it should be possible to implement a plugin for that.

If all you want is to check the values for mu, mu2 and fdir1, they should be visible on the left panel, just find the link you're interested in and check its collision -> surface -> friction. Unfortunately, you will need to reopen the the panel to refresh the numbers (click again on the link's name and see the Property/Value panel update.

I've never tried to change friction dynamically though, so there's a possibility these values might not update (in that case we should create an issue for that).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2015-07-02**:
It does seem that they update (in the sidebar) in response to my plugin changing them. However, values alone are pretty much meaningless, especially when it's not super clear from the Gazebo documentation what direction the primary friction vector is even relative to.